# Right ImageMagick convert svg to png by php from yr.no

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick

have problem to convert svg to png
Meteogramm at svg https://www.yr.no/en/content/67.568007,33.391146/meteogram.svg

i make:

```
$svg = file_get_contents($url);

$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$svg);

$im->setImageFormat("png24");

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $im;

$imagic->clear();
$imagic->destroy();
```

but it view: [my png result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56BqQ.jpg)

Something not enought... [my imageMagick setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG5yq.jpg)
PHP Version 7.4.3

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your ImageMagick is using its internal MSVG to render. That is the least effective of the 3 choices: MSVG, RSVG delegate and Inkscape. I suggest putting Inkscape on your system so that ImageMagick can find it.

In my system using Inkscape for conversion in ImageMagick:

```
convert meteogram.svg meteogram.svg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. i try by exec (convert ...svg ...png), but it same picture how in my first post :((

Comment: Did you put Inkscape on your system?

Comment: Yes of course, i installed it before trying

Comment: Sorry. It works for me. Not sure why it does not for you. If you add -verbose to your command line, does it indicate using Inkscape or MSVG?

Comment: Sorry, sorry sorry , i did it, i make exec (convert...), but i have to do exec (Inkscape  ...) - its work!!! Thank you very much!